# How do I center the text in the header for the Years row?

Tags: tables, center

I am using the following codes:

```
> \begin{table} [h!]    \caption{Alcohol- or Drug-Related Arrests By
> Ethnicity, 2017-2020}     \label{ASUS_drug_arrest_table}  \centering
>   \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}  \hline
>       & 2017 & 2018 & 2019 & 2020\\ \hline    White/Caucasian &  &  &  &\\
>   \hline  Black/African American &  &  &  &\\     \hline  Hispanic/Latino
> &  &  &  &\\  \hline  Native American &  &  &  &\\    \hline  Asian &  &
> &  &\\    \hline  Hawaiian/Part Hawaiian &  &  &   &\\    \hline  Other
> Pacific Islander &  &  &   &\\    \hline  Other &  &  &   &\\     \hline
>   \end{tabular} \end{table}
```

and getting this output:

[image]

I was wondering how the top header representing years can be centered.

Comment: The simplest would be to use `&\centering 2017&\centering 2018 & …`.

Comment: @Bernard I tried with ``  & \centering 2017 & \centering 2018 & \centering 2019 & \centering 2020\\ \hline`` and getting an error that says misplaced \noalign.

Comment: \multico;umn{1}[c}{2017} etc. is the usual approach.

Comment: @OGC have a look athe answer below -- using `thead` from the `makecell` package and `booktabs` for better horizontal lines also removing all verticals

Comment: @OGC:  You're right – there's a problem with `\centering` in the last column. You can circumvent it replacing  `\\ \hline` with   `\tabularnewline \hline` for the heads row, but as the aim of using this command was to simplify w.r.t. using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{…}`, it is debatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, % new
            makecell, % new
            } 
\renewcommand\theadfont{\centering}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.7cm}}  \toprule
              & \thead{2017} & \thead{2018} & \thead{2019} & \thead{2020}\\ \midrule   White/Caucasian &  &  &  &\\
          \midrule  Black/African American &  &  &  &\\     \midrule  Hispanic/Latino
         &  &  &  &\\  \midrule  Native American &  &  &  &\\    \midrule  Asian &  &
         &  &\\    \midrule  Hawaiian/Part Hawaiian &  &  &   &\\    \midrule  Other
         Pacific Islander &  &  &   &\\    \midrule  Other &  &  &   &\\     \bottomrule
           \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

EDIT

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}  \hline
              & \thead{2017} & \thead{2018} & \thead{2019} & \thead{2020}\\ \hline   White/Caucasian &  &  &  &\\           \hline  
              Black/African American &  &  &  &\\     \hline  
              Hispanic/Latino&  &  &  &\\               \hline  
              Native American &  &  &  &\\              \hline  
              Asian &  &&  &\\                          \hline  
              Hawaiian/Part Hawaiian &  &  &   &\\    \hline  
              Other Pacific Islander &  &  &   &\\    \hline  
              Other &  &  &   &\\                       \hline
           \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually want to keep the lines in the table

Comment: not a problem simply revert to your `hlines` as before in the earlier code you have posted in your question -- remove the `toprule`, `midrule` and `bottomrule`

Answer (score 0):

I used the longtable package and it seems to give me what I wanted:

```
\begin{longtable}[h!]{|p{4cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}     
    \caption{Alcohol- or Drug-Related Arrests By Ethnicity, 2017-2020}
    \label{ASUS_drug_arrest_table} \\
    
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2017} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2018} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2019} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2020}\\ \hline 
        
    White/Caucasian &  &  &  &\\
    \hline
    Black/African American &  &  &  &\\
    \hline
    Hispanic/Latino &  &  &  &\\
    \hline
    Native American &  &  &  &\\
    \hline
    Asian &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    Hawaiian/Part Hawaiian &  &  &   &\\
    \hline
    Other Pacific Islander &  &  &   &\\
    \hline
    Other &  &  &   &\\
    \hline
    
\end{longtable}
```

Thanks for the comments!